# adding dll to C# project

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, windows-store

I have created dll out of a c# project say "a.dll", this project has some UIs with Charm Flyouts.

 now i am adding this dll into another C# project say "b",so that i can see the Charm Flyouts

 in the "b" project. but i am not able to see the Flyouts , I don't know what exactly the problem is. For sake i changed the Page name as i thought there may be some conflict between 

page name as both the projects have same page name as MainPage.

Please help me to do this,thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is it, but I've ran into a somewhat similar problem with images from ProjectA, where I want them to be shown in ProjectB. This however is not possible in Store Projects, the image should be in the same project and cannot be referenced from ProjectB to ProjectA (without returning any error).

A workaround (if possible) would be to put the two projects in the same solution and add the charm flyouts (if they are images) as linked items in ProjectB...

Hope this gets you towards a solution.